solution-verification | Find $x$ from the some equalities
the problem
Find $x$ from the equalities:
a) $(3-2\sqrt{2})^x=3+2\sqrt{2}$
b) $(\sqrt{3}-2)^x=7-4\sqrt{3}$
c) $(5+2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-2x}=5-2\sqrt{6}$
my solution
a) $(3-2\sqrt{2})^x=3+2\sqrt{2} $   and then I multiplied by $ (3-2\sqrt{2})$
$(3-2\sqrt{2})^{x+1}=1$ and because $3-2\sqrt{2}$ is not equal to $1$ and we know that $a^n=1$ where $a$ is not $1$ means that $n=0$, then $x+1=0\implies x=-1$
b) $(\sqrt{3}-2)^x=7-4\sqrt{3}=(2-\sqrt{3})^2=(-(\sqrt{3}-2))^2=(\sqrt{3}-2)^2$, then we divide by $(\sqrt{3}-2)^2$ and applying the same statement from a) we get that $x=2$
c) $(5+2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-2x}=5-2\sqrt{6}$ and we multiply by $5+2\sqrt{6}$
$(5+2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-2x+1}=1$ and applying the same statement from a) we get that $x^2-2x+1=0=(x-1)^2\implies  x=1$
As you can see I marked this as solution-verification. Im not sure if the statement that $a^n=1$ where $a$ is not $1$ means that $n=0$ is correct and if I explained very well what I did.
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Another way to reason in a) is that $$3+2\sqrt{2}=\frac{(3+2\sqrt{2})(3-2\sqrt{2})}{3-2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{9-1}{3-2\sqrt{2}}=(3-2\sqrt{2})^{-1}$$
So now you have $(3-2\sqrt{2})^x=(3-2\sqrt{2})^{-1}$ for which $x=-1$ is clearly a solution.

It depends on the set of numbers from which $a$ and $n$ may be chosen. Clearly $(-1)^2=1$ and there are other solutions with certain values of $a$ on the unit circle in the complex plane; but crucially in your problems the base has absolute value different from 1 which makes the argument valid.
For all complex $a$ with $|a|\neq1$ and integer $n$ consider that $1=|a^n|=|a|^n,$ observe that $a$ cannot be $0$ and then take the (real) logarithm of both sides.
Fractional or even irrational $n$ could be treated similarly, provided that you remain careful about the definition of $a^n,$ e.g., $a^{m+n}$ may not always be equal to $a^m.a^n$

Thank you for your answer! Another question, in final, my solution is correct?

I think it is, yes.
